# How to get dynamic data form database to show on the line chart?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, chart.js

I hey a dashboard to show a line chart that contains a dynamic data from table users. My chart will show all the user, that will get according the updated_at column. Moreover, I really struggle how to get data from database that will show by column updated_at and display data by month and year, then display it on the chart. Let me demonstrate my code:

My routes:

```
Route::get('dashboard','App\Http\Controllers\Web\SampleController@dashboard')->name('dashboard.list');
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Web;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;
class SampleController extends Controller
{
      // How to get data from database, I need help
      public function dashboard()
    {
        $year = Carbon::now()->year; 
        $month = Carbon::now()->month -1; 
        $data = User::whereMonth('updated_at', '=',$month)->get()->count();
        
        //print($data);
        //die('hello');

        // $all_user = User::where('id')
        //     ->where('updated_at')
        //     ->get()
        //     ->count(); 
        // $userData = User::select(DB::raw("COUNT(*) as count"))
        //             ->whereYear('created_at', date('Y'))
        //             ->groupBy(DB::raw("Month(created_at)"))
        //             ->pluck('count');
        return view('layouts.user.dashboard.dashboard',compact('data'));
    }
}
```

View with boostrap 5:

```
@section('title', 'dashboard') 
@section('page_id', 'dashboard')

@section('content')
<body>
    <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
        <div class="pull-left">
            <h3><strong>Dashboard</strong></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="input-group input-daterange">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="2012-04-05">
    <div class="input-group-addon">to</div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="2012-04-19">
</div>

<!--This button will show data by month and year-->
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic mixed styles example">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Month</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Year</button>
</div>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
</body>
@endsection
```

resource/js/dashboard/index.js:

```
import $ from "jquery";
require("bootstrap-datepicker");

import {
    Chart,
    ArcElement,
    LineElement,
    BarElement,
    PointElement,
    BarController,
    BubbleController,
    DoughnutController,
    LineController,
    PieController,
    PolarAreaController,
    RadarController,
    ScatterController,
    CategoryScale,
    LinearScale,
    LogarithmicScale,
    RadialLinearScale,
    TimeScale,
    TimeSeriesScale,
    Decimation,
    Filler,
    Legend,
    Title,
    Tooltip,
    SubTitle,
} from "chart.js";

Chart.register(
    ArcElement,
    LineElement,
    BarElement,
    PointElement,
    BarController,
    BubbleController,
    DoughnutController,
    LineController,
    PieController,
    PolarAreaController,
    RadarController,
    ScatterController,
    CategoryScale,
    LinearScale,
    LogarithmicScale,
    RadialLinearScale,
    TimeScale,
    TimeSeriesScale,
    Decimation,
    Filler,
    Legend,
    Title,
    Tooltip,
    SubTitle
);
class Dashboard {
    onLoad() {
        var data1 = [];
        $(".input-daterange input").each(function () {
            $(this).datepicker("clearDates");
        });

        $("#btnChangeMode").on("click", (e) => {
            this.mode = 1;
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard",
            data: {},
            type: "GET",
            success: () => {
                let data = [
                   { $data: "updated_at" },// I tried to get data but I can't, I really need help
            [2, 10, 13, 27, 36, 31, 70],// I try write this to show the line, it does not matter
                    [12, 19, 13, 37, 16, 13, 17],
                ];
                this.drawChart(data);
            },
        });
    }

    drawChart(data) {
        var data1 = data[0];
        var data2 = data[1];
        var data3 = data[2];
        var labels = [];

        if ((this.mode = 1)) {
            labels = [
                "Jan",
                "Feb",
                "Mar",
                "Apr",
                "May",
                "Jun",
                "Jul",
                "Aug",
                "Sep",
                "Oct",
                "Nov",
                "Dec",
            ];
        }

        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: "line",
            data: {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: "All user", // Show all user
                        data: data1,
                        borderColor: "rgba(104,226,187,255)",
                    },
                    {
                        label: "All creator", 
                        data: data2,
                        borderColor: "rgba(88,145,254,255)",
                    },
                    {
                        label: "All general user",
                        data: data3,
                        borderColor: "rgba(224,116,116,255)",
                    },
                ],
            },
        });
    }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Database
[image: My database]

Comment: you need to create an endpoint where you'll show chart data in a json format let's say it's example.com/chartjs. Once that's done then you need to get that URL i.e. `example.com/chartjs` in your ajax URL call to fetch all the data and afterwards it's simple formatting to show the correct data.

Comment: How to do that, this is my first time doing chart could you show me some example ?

Comment: I think you need 2 array from back-end, `labels` and `data`?

Comment: You mean 2 labels for month and year , 2 data for every month and every year

Comment: If you're targeting two buttons i.e. every month and every year then you need to create two endpoints with monthly and yearly options. In simple words labels and data as said by @sta

Comment: Could you show me some example code, please I really do not know how to do this